# Retrieve tab URL when dragging tab into an HTML page

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm working on a Chrome Extension and I need to be able to drag a Chrome tab into the HTML page. I can not find any way to retrieve the URL of the dragged Chrome tab. Is this possible? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: I dont have an answer for you, but this looks like a step in the right direction https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#event-onDetached

Comment: Your extension can't accept a tab being dropped as a form of input in the way you describe it. You can do something like getting the most recent tab and in an onclick event in your extension you get the TAB_ID and get the URL from that, but since the tab dragging is being handled by Chrome itself it can't be interfered with by an extension for security reasons. I suggest simply copying the URL from the adress bar into your extensions window and using that info directly, I understand it's not the answer you wanted but I really don't see a way to get what you want.